# Restrict clickable area of leftbarbuttonitem to the size of custom uibarbuttonitem

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have implemented a SWReveal control on my app. To triger the action I have a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view. Well, everything is working fine, but I have noticed that I can fire the event even when clicking far away from the image (image of about 44px wide...and clicking up to 100px).

I have been searching for a while, and the best solution that I ve found (defining a custom button and instantiating a UIBarButtonItem with "initWithCustomView")

This is my previous code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:_revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;
```

And the code with the "solution":

```
//create the image for your button, and set the frame for its size
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
//init a normal UIButton using that image
UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:_revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//finally, create your UIBarButtonItem using that button
UIBarButtonItem* revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;
```

With this later code I know I have a correct sized button (I ve set backgroundColor, and checked the correct size of the button), but still firing the action when tapping far away from the button.

¿any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not answering your question, but: Why would you want to do that? There is a reason that iOS increases the touchable area of bar button items. You seem to have a menu button there (as the only button on the left) and I can really not see any advantage of explicitly making the touchable area smaller than the default. And: Test this on a device, not on the simulator!!

Comment: Your users will kill you if you have a touchable area of only about 20x20pt (just guessing the size of your icon).. ;-)

Comment: I have read the Humans guideline of apple, and I do not pretend make such a litle buttons, but, as I said in the question, the problem is that the selectable area is much much more bigger than the actual size of the button (you can see the same problem in other famous app, where you have a custom image working as button, but tapping far away from it will fire the action. But in facebook app you will see that this beaheaviour corrected. :)

Comment: @raululm I am having the exact same issue with my `leftBarButtonItem`, have you resolved this or accepted it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `button.clipsToBounds = YES;`, but I have to agree with the other comments, as per Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/ios-human-interface-guidelines/id877942287?mt=11), every tappable area should be at least 44x44.

Comment: I've tried it already, and dind't work :( I absolutely agree with you about tappable area, but navigation area of the navigation bar when you have only one button is bigger than the actual size of the button (and my button measures 44x44), and for my clients it is a little weird to touch when there is no button, and the button gets tapped anyway. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

the custom view route seems to work for me, but i did find another solution you can try if that's not working for you. it seems like the tappable area only extends as far over until it hits something the user can tap. i have a title view that the user can tap to do something, so the tappable area of my leftbarbuttonitem stops there. but i also tried adding another uiview with userinteractionenabled set to yes just slightly to the right of the leftbarbuttonitem and that seems to stop the area from extending. i was able to use just the two line standard code instead of the custom. not sure if this will work for you or not

Answer (score 0):

```
It is hard to make uibarbuttonitem touch area override. We can achieve the same using subclassing uinavigationbar.

File-New-CocoaTouch Class-UINavigationBar- Name it.

This is mine:

import UIKit
import Foundation

let navigationItem : UINavigationItem = UINavigationItem()

class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    }
    func addUIButtonToUIBarButtonitems(leftButton:UIButton,leftButtonFrame:CGRect,rightButton:UIButton,rightButtonFrame:CGRect)
    {
        let leftView = UIView(frame: leftButtonFrame)
        leftView.addSubview(leftButton)

        let leftItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftView)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem

        let rightView = UIView(frame: rightButtonFrame)
        rightView.addSubview(rightButton)

        let rightItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightView)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem

        items = [navigationItem]
    }
}

I have a method for setting uibuttons as uibarbuttonitems. On View Controller, I will add two unbuttons and will pass the same to the navigation bar. The frame of the unbutton will be the click area of the respective uibattonitem.

class CustomNavBarVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.styleCustomNavigationBar()
    }

    func styleCustomNavigationBar() {

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

        let navigationBar : CustomNavigationBar = CustomNavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 64.0))

        //menu button
        let menubutton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,30,30))
        menubutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        menubutton.addTarget(self, action: "backButtonDidClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        //search button
        let searchbutton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,30,30))
        searchbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "search1x"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        searchbutton.addTarget(self, action: "backButtonDidClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


        navigationBar.addUIButtonToUIBarButtonitems(menubutton, leftButtonFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,30,30), rightButton: searchbutton, rightButtonFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,30,30))

        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
    }

    func backButtonDidClicked()
    {
        print("CLICK ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `button.clipsToBounds = YES;`

This may help you.